# Prime spectra of polynomial algebras

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Are there fields $K$ and $L$ such that $\operatorname{Spec}(K[x])$ and $\operatorname{Spec}(L[x])$ are homeomorphic but $\operatorname{Spec}(K[x,y])$ and $\operatorname{Spec}(L[x,y])$ are not homeomorphic?

(Here $x$ and $y$ are indeterminates.)

**EDIT.** Note that $\operatorname{Spec}(K[x,y])$ and $\operatorname{Spec}(L[x,y])$ are homeomorphic if and only if they are order-isomorphic.

This is because any closed subset of the spectrum of a noetherian ring is a finite union of subsets of the form $V(\mathfrak p)$ where $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal.

Comment: Note that $\operatorname{Spec}(K[x])$ is just the soberization of the cofinite topology on a set of cardinality $|K|+\aleph_0$ (the irreducible elements of $K[x]$), so your hypothesis is just that $|K|+\aleph_0=|L|+\aleph_0$.